# What is the result of XOR between two Bernoulli random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider two Bernoulli random variables $X$ and $Y$ with probabilities $p_1$ and $p_2$.

Now $Z = X \oplus Y$, $\oplus$ is a logical XOR operator.

Is $Z$ a Bernoulli random variable and what is its probability mass function?

This question occurred to me when I was trying to come up with the best way to add bernoulli noise to a bernoulli random variable in my model and XOR operator seemed to do what I want.

Comment: Are you assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent?  If so, just look at the $4$ possible cases ($0$ or $1$ for each of $X$ and $Y$).  If not, you haven't enough information.

Comment: yes, $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $Z$ variable is 0 in the case $X = Y$, which happens whenever $X = Y = 0$ or $X = Y = 1$. Thus, since the two are independent:
$$p_Z(0) = (1-p_1)(1-p_2) + p_1p_2$$
Likewise, $Z$ is 1 if $X ≠ Y$, so either $X = 1, Y = 0$ or $X = 0, Y=1$.
$$p_Z(1) = p_1(1-p_2) + p_2(1-p_1)$$
Notice that these two values do, in fact, add up to 1: $p_Z(0)+p_Z(1)=1$. So $Z$ is a Bernoulli variable with probability $p_1(1-p_2) + p_2(1-p_1)$.